# Why is the proper conversion of nanoseconds to seconds changing in Java when I write to the console?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, seconds, datetime-conversion

I'm currently cleaning my game loops timing in java, but I'm having a very strange issue with nanoseconds to seconds conversion.

For some reason when I don't write to the console getting the nanoseconds passed into a time delta (measured in seconds) works properly by dividing by 100,000,000. This I immediately found strange given there are 1000,000,000 nanoseconds in a second, so I tried measuring how many loops were running per second and printing it to the console when it flies above my needed FPS. This for a completely unknown reason caused the game to insanely slow down requiring a divide by 1000,000,000 for the delta to reach its proper value. I'm completely lost as to why this would be.

Below is the loop as it currently stands. The "Problem Trigger" line when commented out changes the "Problem Lines" functioning causing a need to change the value its divided by to convert it to the proper units

```
while (isRunning)
{
    now = System.nanoTime();
    delta = (double)(now - lastUpdateTime) / 1000000000; //problem line
    timer += delta;
    timerplus += delta;
    ticks++;
    gamePanel.Update(delta);
    lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();

    if (ticks / timerplus > 60)
    {
        System.out.println("fast"); //problem trigger?
    }

    gamePanel.Render(delta);
    timer = 0;
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, this is just a plain confusing issue, if the information is any help I'm using `JPanel` and `JFrame`, writing and compiling in an unmodified Eclipse IDE.

**EDIT: okay so after trying out that code it worked (all I did was move some stuff around) as a triple check I went back to how it was layed out when the problem occurred**

```
    while (isRunning)
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta = (double)(now - lastUpdateTime) / 1000000000;
        timer += delta;
        timerplus += delta;
        ticks++;
        gamePanel.Update(delta);
        lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        if (ticks / timerplus > 120)
        {
            //System.out.println("wow");
        }
        if (timer >= (double)1 / TICKS_PER_SECOND)
        {
            gamePanel.Render(delta);
            timer = 0;
        }
        if (timerplus >= 1)
        {
            System.out.println("FPS: " + ticks);
            ticks = 0;
            timerplus = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now they run differently depending on whether the "wow" line is commented out or not, still absolutely bizarre but given the differences from the cleaned version I first posted and the odd beefy one I just posted hopefully the problem is easier to spot.

Comment: What is the type of `timer` and `timerplus`? int or double?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you're showing. `delta` will accurately hold the number of seconds between `now` and `lastUpdateTime` represented as a `double`

Comment: so I gave it another go and yes the snippet I posted worked fine commented or not, which is strange because I only changed a few lines before posting it, regardless I've edited with the unchanged snippet which does produce the issue.
its still confusing why that 1 line effects the loop speed but looking at the printed delta when commented its a steady 3.019E-6, when not commented it flickers wildly from 1.449E-5 to 8.452E-6

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant comment yet because of my reputation, I will just throw this out there, try making 1000000000 into 1000000000.0 or 1000000000L so that it will be a long. Maybe it gets truncated to an int.

Also, why dont you throw this into its own Thread? If it is running on the EDT, that could explain why your program is slowing down considerably.

Comment: Truncation isn't an issue - ints go up to just over 2 billion.

Comment: Operands get implicitly promoted to the higher type in Java. Since the OP's numerator is explicitly cast to double, the divisor gets promoted to double as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially losing time.  Here's a snipped version of your function:

```
while (isRunning)
{
    now = System.nanoTime();
    delta = (double)(now - lastUpdateTime) / 1000000000; //problem line
     //snip 1
    lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
     //snip 2
}
```

Over time, if you sum up all the deltas, you'll be increasing at a rate slightly below realtime.  How much below depends on how long the operations between "now" and "lastUpdateTime" being set take.  If, for example, the operations in "snip1" and "snip2" took approximately the same amount of time, you'd see a rate of ~1/2 realtime.

For a concrete example, assuming your update method takes ~15 microseconds and your "render" method takes ~10:
On iteration 1, "now" is initially set to some time X.  "lastUpdateTime" then gets set to X+15000.
On iteration 2, "now" is set to X + 25000.  The delta you're passing in is therefore 10000, even though the change in "now" between the two iterations is actually 25000.

The reason you're having to change your divisor on the "problem line" when you add/remove that printout is that I/O is *slow*, so it changes the ratio of time spent in snip1 and snip2 rather dramatically.

What you probably actually want to do is:

```
while (isRunning)
{
    now = System.nanoTime();
    delta = (double)(now - lastUpdateTime) / 1000000000; //problem line
     //snip 1
    lastUpdateTime = now;
     //snip 2
}
```

This will guarantee that if gamePanel.update(delta) were to keep an ongoing sum of the passed-in deltas, it would match up fairly precisely with elapsed wall-clock time over the long run.